# For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find a function $f$ which is differentiable $n$ times at $0$, but not $n+1$ times.

Tags: calculus, functions

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, (in this problem $\mathbb{N}$ starts at $n = 1$) find a function $f$ which is differentiable $n$ times at $0$, but not $n+1$ times.

The function I chose is the following:

$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x^{n+1} &\mbox{if } x \le 0\\
x^{n} &\mbox{if } x > 0 \end{cases}
$$

Now I can't think of the best way to prove that $f$ is differentiable  $n$ times at $0$ but not $n+1$ times.

Comment: For n=1, your function isn't differentiable at 0

Comment: Here's a solution for $n = 0$: $f_0(x) = |x|$. If you were to integrate that, say, with $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) ~ dt$, what would the derivative of $g$ be? How many times differentiable would it be at $x = 0$?

Comment: He can also go one step further with his example I think, i.e increase the exponenet by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Check the function

> $$ f(x) = x^{1/2 + n} ,$$

Which is differentiable $n$ times, but not $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=|x|^{n+1}$ is differentiable  n times but not $n+1$ times. If $n$ is even then satisfy the above condition.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x^\alpha\sin(x^{-1})$ for a suitable $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy function which is differentiable n times but not (n+1) times at $x=0$  is

$$ f(x) = x^n|x| \ \  \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: For those wondering why. One has to rewrite it as $x^{n-1} * (x|x|)$ and find the derivative of it using product rule. Notice that derivative of $x|x|$ is $2|x|$. A pattern will occur such that $f^{(n)} = (n+1)!|x|$ the derivative of which does not exist in $x_0 = 0$ due to (|x|)' not existing there.