# what function that is differentiable 2019 times, but is not differentiable 2020 times?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Please give a example of function that is differentiate 2019 times, but is not differentiate 2020 times

Comment: Find a function that is differentiable $2018$ times, but not $2019$ times, and take its indefinite integral.

Comment: Integrate $|x|$ 2019 times

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611296/for-every-n-in-mathbbn-find-a-function-f-which-is-differentiable-n-ti

Answer (score 4):

Take a non-differentiable continuous function, like $f(x) = |x|$ and integrate it the correct number of times.

Comment: is this same as lxlx^2019 ?

Comment: @chlcll You just integrate both branches differently, and it's definitely not the same, but equivalent

Answer (score 2):

$f(x) = x^{2019 + 1/3}$ is differentiable 2019 times everywhere, but it does not have a 2020th derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: how about x^(1/2 + 2019)

Comment: Would work too, except that only has a domain of $[0, \infty)$ whereas $x^{2019+1/3}$ has a domain of all of $\mathbb{R}$.